# In Rust, how to template functions returning `impl Iterator<Item = String>`

Tags: rust

I am attempting template some functions and finding it difficult to template functions returning Iterators. They occur as syntax errors

```
struct A;
impl A {
    fn x(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = String> {
        todo!()
    }
}
```

The syntax error is:

```
Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0277]: `()` is not an iterator
 --> src/lib.rs:3:20
  |
3 |     fn x(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = String> {
  |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `()` is not an iterator
  |
  = help: the trait `Iterator` is not implemented for `()`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error
```

Comment: Interesting corner case of type inference. It looks like a `todo!()` or other diverging macro will just default to `()` in the present of an `impl` trait return type. I would say it's a bug, but I can't think of what the behavior *should* be. It certainly has to pick some concrete type to put there, after all...

Comment: @SilvioMayolo It could stay as `!`, but the reason it is so is [a regression](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/67225).

Answer (score 2):

The standard library's `Empty::new()` is available to provide a template default. However, the standard approach is to use the provided constructor function: `std::iter::empty()`

```
struct A;
impl A {
    fn x(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = String> {
        std::iter::empty()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason that this doesn't work is that `todo!()` returns `!` (aka `never`). Since `!` cannot have a value, it can be reconciled to any other type; that is, it's concrete type is inferred based on assignment, similar to a generic return type, `T`.  But `impl Iterator` isn't concrete either, so each one is relying on the other for type inferrence, creating a kind of circular reference.

You can fix this by making the body a concrete iterator type, as in [George's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74792619/493729), which I won't duplicate here. Alternatively you can make the *return* type concrete. For example:

```
use std::iter::Empty;
fn x(&self) -> Empty<String> {
    std::iter::empty()
}
```

Type inference can be convenient and can reduce the amount of noise in type annotations, but you need to provide sufficient information, so the type can be inferred in one direction or the other.

Comment: This is not accurate. `todo!()` does have a concrete return type (the never type), but it defaults to coerce to the unit type if a concrete type cannot be inferred from the surrounding context.